# Google Sheets - Query importrange select where date is today

Tags: google-sheets

I have a worksheet that I am importing data into. Column 4 of the source worksheet contains dates. I would like to import only the rows that are from today() date.

My starting point is:

```
={unique(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A3:L1000"), "select Col9,Col1,Col4,Col3,Col5 where Col1 is not null order by Col4"));}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adapting the where clause:

`where Col1 is not null and Col4 = date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`

So the query becomes:

```
={unique(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A3:L1000"), "select Col9,Col1,Col4,Col3,Col5 where Col1 is not null and Col4 = date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' "));}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think he needs to order by Col4 if what he only wants are rows with the date today.

Comment: Thanks. I left his query as it was; I just added `and Col4 = date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`. Like you say, the sort is not relevant if the new query only brings back dates for today.

Comment: I understand. Still it works so it's not that big of a deal.